# Is it possible that galaxies formed from incredibly fast neutron star collisions?

Tags: special-relativity, galaxies, neutron-stars

In the recent [Kurzgesagt](https://youtu.be/udFxKZRyQt4) youtube video there is mention of how neutron star collisions are the likely candidates for creating the heavier elements in the universe. It is also possible that it created more mass of the heavy elements than the sum of the two neutron star masses before collision due to relativity.

This got me to thinking if neutron stars were traveling fast enough in the early universe and they collided it could produce enough matter to create a galaxy while also creating a supermassive black hole at the center. In doing some searches I could not find anything on this topic and would be happy if someone could point me to some material.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

- Neutron stars are formed from massive stars, so we do not expect to see neutron stars in the early universe (massive stars would have to form *first*, and then they would have to die, which can take hundreds of millions of years).
- A typical neutron star has mass of about one solar mass. Comparatively the mass of the Milky Way is about $10^{12}$ solar masses. That's $1$ with $12$ zeroes behind it. The gap is tremendous.

Answer (score 0):

> It is also possible that it created **more mass** of the heavy elements **than the sum** of the two neutron star masses before collision due to relativity.

No.

The law of conservation states that for any closed system (the universe) the system's mass cannot change, so quantity can neither be added nor be removed.

Wikipedia: "[Conservation of Mass - Mass conservation remains correct if energy is not lost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservation_of_mass#Mass_conservation_remains_correct_if_energy_is_not_lost)":

> For the special type of mass called invariant mass, changing the inertial frame of observation for a whole closed system has no effect on the measure of invariant mass of the system, which remains both conserved and invariant (unchanging), even for different observers who view the entire system. Invariant mass is a system combination of energy and momentum, which is invariant for any observer, because in any inertial frame, the energies and momenta of the various particles always add to the same quantity (the momentum may be negative, so the addition amounts to a subtraction). The invariant mass is the relativistic mass of the system when viewed in the center of momentum frame. It is the minimum mass which a system may exhibit, as viewed from all possible inertial frames.
>
> The conservation of both relativistic and invariant mass applies even to systems of particles created by pair production, where energy for new particles may come from kinetic energy of other particles, or from one or more photons as part of a system that includes other particles besides a photon. Again, neither the relativistic nor the invariant mass of totally closed (that is, isolated) systems changes when new particles are created. However, different inertial observers will disagree on the value of this conserved mass, if it is the relativistic mass (i.e., relativistic mass is conserved but not invariant). However, all observers agree on the value of the conserved mass if the mass being measured is the invariant mass (i.e., invariant mass is both conserved and invariant).
>
> The mass-energy equivalence formula gives a different prediction in non-isolated systems, since if energy is allowed to escape a system, both relativistic mass and invariant mass will escape also. In this case, the mass-energy equivalence formula predicts that the change in mass of a system is associated with the change in its energy due to energy being added or subtracted: $\Delta m=\Delta E/c^{2}$. This form involving changes was the form in which this famous equation was originally presented by Einstein. In this sense, mass changes in any system are explained simply if the mass of the energy added or removed from the system, are taken into account.